# IE 9 64 bit Rendering Issue

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highstock JS v1.2.4.

I have created a chart containing multiple series. These series are clubbed together as group. So, I am drawing a Line separator to separate these groups using

```
 axis.addPlotLine({
                id: 'separator',
                value: minVal, // minVal is dynamic
                width: global.lineWidth, // global.lineWidth is 2
                color: timelineDefaults.colors.separatorLine, // Line Color
                dashStyle: 'solid'
            });
```

Also, I have added 
`plotBorderColor: '#346691',
 plotBorderWidth:1,
 ..`
 with `chart:{...}`

It was working smooth till I have upgraded to Windows 7 64 bit and to IE 9 64 bit inherently. The same code works If I test them under IE 32 bit 7 - 8 9  and 9 Compatibility mode).

Here is the screens[image]

This is from IE 64 bit
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compatibility mode is not supported, only native browsers.

Comment: Our product runs on IE control which takes Compatibility mode by default.

Comment: It works with 32 bit Compatibility modes. So, I guess you need to test this with 64 bit IE versions.

Comment: Full compatibility list is published here: http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/compatibility

Comment: Ok.. Let's skip IE compatibility mode part. So, It should work on "IE 6 + " 64-bit version right ?

Comment: We do intend to support compatibility mode as well. IE9 compatibility usually renders the same as IE8.

Comment: I tried to recreate this in my Windows 7 64 bit setup, but to no avail. Created a live demo, http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/9MBur/1/. Here's the result: http://screencast.com/t/YYclXcaYSPcp . Are you able to reproduce the problem with that Fiddle? If not, can you do any changes to crash it?